# How to make a flex child full height and scroll X and Y

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a simple sidebar layout using flex:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.pagedata {
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      This is the header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div>SideBar:</div>
        <div>Option 2</div>
        <div>Option 3</div>
        <div>Option 4</div>
        <div>Option 1</div>
        <div>Option 2</div>
        <div>Option 3</div>
        <div>Option 4</div>
        <div>Option 2</div>
        <div>Option 3</div>
        <div>Option 4</div>
        <div>Option 2</div>
        <div>Option 3</div>
        <div>Option 4</div>
        <div>Option 2</div>
        <div>Option 3</div>
        <div>Option 4</div>
        <div>Option 2</div>
        <div>Option 3</div>
        <div>Option 4</div>
        <div>Option 2</div>
        <div>Option 3</div>
        <div>Option 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="pagedata">
        <p>Content Page</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
        <p>This is the page data</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

As it is the flex child's are not getting full heigh if screen height is bigger than content, and if screen height is smaller than content, the whole page is scrolling vertically.

How can I make the flex children scroll their own content using CSS:

- `sidebar` must scroll vertically (Y)
- `pagedata` must scroll horizontally and vertically (X and Y)

Both of them I want to fill full height (even if content is smaller than height).

Comment: margin:0 to body + height:100% to wrapper + min-height:0 to content + flex-grow:1 to content and pagedate

Comment: ^ not sure what is different from this old question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/61027161/8620333) and why you didn't apply the styles I commented there

Comment: Is `min-height: 0` a default? [from w3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp). It makes all the difference (without it does not work)

Comment: from one of the duplicate questions of your old question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/8620333 .. if you read it you will understand why the need of min-height:0 and what is the default value (reading the duplicate question is important for you to understand, we are not closing question to simply bother you but to give you what you need to understand in order to solve your issue)

Comment: @Temani Afif: It's difficult to find out a solution if we have to look to 4 different duplicates with different subjects/answers. We never know what are you're pointint out exactly in a small comment. This question is directed to flex child behaviour, not so generic. I've applied your comments in the last question and did not solve the problem. A simple question and aswer would be much more valuable on this cases, and for future users to find out. How the hell I would imagine my problem would be related to "flex shrink past content size"... Keep SO flowing - this is what makes it so powerfull.